# jpackage creates 2 copies of JRE

Tags: java, javafx

I use `jpackage` (with JDK 14) for creating a standalone JavaFX application.

The output of `jpackage` looks strange, it consists of two the same copies of JRE and all files in `app` folder, except `App.cfg` file, can be deleted without any problem.

**Does `jpackage` can do not generate unnecessary files?**

---

What I have:

I have a simple project created from Maven archetype `org.openjfx:javafx-archetype-simple:0.0.3`. 
And I just added `maven-shade-plugin` for creating jar with dependencies and a simple launching class for it (like `NewMain` class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing/52654791#52654791)).

I do:

```
mvn package
mvn javafx:jlink
jpackage --package-type app-image --dest targetApp --name App --runtime-image target/image --main-jar testApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --input target
```

As result I have two folders with JRE (absolutely the same ones):

- `targetApp\App\runtime`
- `targetApp\App\app\image`

And all files (and folders) (JRE (~53 MB), Jar (~9 MB), classes...) in `targetApp\App\app` can be safely deleted, except `App.cfg` file.

After deleting these files I run `targetApp\App\App.exe` and it works fine.

*The deleting reduces the size of `App` from 118 to 56 MB.*

---

**An additional question**: I use Windows and `jpackage` generates the result for Windows (a lot of `dll` files and `exe`), do I can create a standalone application in Windows for Mac and Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You get this result because you already created an uber-jar which contains everything in addition to what you specified via `--input target` which, according to the documentation, has the following effect.

```
All files in the input directory will be packaged into the
application image.
```

Try whether it works to just remove the option `--input target` or don't create the uber-jar. Instead use the maven-dependency-plugin to copy all dependencies into a single folder, say `target/libs`, and then explicitly specify `--input target/libs`.

Your second question:
You cannot cross-create applications for other targets, if that is your question.

Comment: Yeah, it's the reason. But `--input` is a required option. Well, I have specified `outputDirectory` for `maven-shade-plugin` and `maven-jar-plugin` so I have the directory that contains only jar file for `--input`, but anyway I have to manually to delete this jar from `targetApp\App\app` later.

Comment: Should say, that it's strange, that I can delete the jar from `targetApp\App\app` and the program still works. I don't see any file that may contains the program logic, but it works. I have even checked the work in clear Windows in VM.

Comment: Upd: they are probably in `targetApp\App\runtime\lib\modules` file.

Comment: I have tested it a bit more. So, it's not important that type of JAR you use, you get the same result for JAR, uber-JAR, JAR-with-dependencies (JAR and JARs in libs folder). The difference is only one – unnecessary JAR or JARs in `targetApp\App\app` folder that you should manually delete.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the JPackageScriptFX project on GitHub. It contains a sample multi-module maven project structure and build scripts for Mac and Windows that will build all available package types and executables for both platforms. You can find it here: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Answer (score 0):

My solution without Oracle's `jpackage`:

## AdoptOpenJDK + `jpackager` + macOS => `.pkg`, `.dmg`

- Download [AdoptOpenJDK_13](https://adoptopenjdk.net/). Unzip and put into `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk`
- Download `jpackager` for (in my case osx) from https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-September/022500.html. Unzip.
- Copy `jdk.packager.jar` and `jpackager` to the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/bin` (!!!)
- In `/yourworkspace/target` should be the *programA.jar* file. (In my case it is a small program created with OpenJFX + openjdk13)
- The `/yourworkspace/jlink` denotes on your JRE with `bin`,`lib` etc. you might have created via `jlink`. (In my case I have my custom JRE + JavaFX modules)
- The `/yourworkspace/icons` contains *.icns* .
- create *jpackager.command* file in your `workspace` with the content:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
ABSPATH=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd -P)
launcher=`ls $ABSPATH/target/*.jar`
for eachfile in $launcher
do
    if [ -f "$eachfile" ];then
        echo Creating .pkg ...
        echo "$eachfile"
        basename="${eachfile##*/}"
        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jpackager \
        create-installer \
        --runtime-image $ABSPATH/jlink \
        --name ProgramA \
        --input $ABSPATH/target \
        --main-jar $basename \
        --version 1.0 \
        --copyright "Nikita Gromov 2020" \
        --name "ProgramA-macos" \
        --mac-bundle-name "ProgramA" \
        --output $ABSPATH/appimage \
        --icon $ABSPATH/icons/20200220101822955_easyicon_net_32.icns
     fi
done
```

Double click on *jpackager.command* which is located in `/yourworkspace` and wait until the `jpackager` has created *ProgramA-macos-1.0.pkg* and *ProgramA-macos-1.0.dmg* under `/yourworkspace/appimage`

My solution without Oracle's `jpackage`:

## AdoptOpenJDK + `jpackager` + Windows => `.msi`

- Install [WiX](https://wixtoolset.org/) (!!!) **Important step.**
- Download [AdoptOpenJDK_11](https://adoptopenjdk.net/). Will be installed under `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot`
- Download `jpackager` (in this case win) from https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-September/022500.html. Unzip.
- Copy `jdk.packager.jar` and `jpackager` to the `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot\bin` (!!!)
- In `/yourworkspace/target` should be the *programA.jar* file. (In my case it is a small program created with OpenJFX + openjdk11)
- The `/yourworkspace/jlink` denotes on your JRE with `bin`,`lib` etc. you might have created via `jlink`. (In my case I have my custom JRE + JavaFX modules)
- The `/yourworkspace/icons` contains *.icns* .
- create *jpackager.bat* file in your `/yourworkspace` folder with the content:

```sh
set openjdk=C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot\bin
set saveto=%cd%
cd %openjdk%
jpackager create-installer --runtime-image %saveto%/jlink --input %saveto%/target --main-jar ProgramA.jar --version 1.0 --copyright "Nikita Gromov" --name "ProgramA-win" --output %saveto%/appimage --icon %saveto%/icons/icon.ico --win-menu --win-shortcut --win-dir-chooser
```

**Note** The *ProgramA.jar* should be in `/yourworkspace/target` path (!!!)

Double click on *jpackager.bat* which is located in `/yourworkspace` and wait until the `jpackager` has created *ProgramA-win-1.0.msi* under `/yourworkspace/appimage`

## Custom JRE + JavaFX mods on Windows

Create `/yourworkspace/jlink.bat` file. The content of it should be:

```sh
SET openjdk=C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot\bin
SET fx=C:\Programme\AdoptOpenJDK\javafx-jmods-11.0.2
set saveto=%cd%
cd %openjdk%
jlink --module-path %fx% --add-modules=javafx.base --add-modules=javafx.controls --add-modules=javafx.fxml --add-modules=javafx.graphics --add-modules=javafx.web --add-modules=javafx.media --add-modules=javafx.swing --bind-services --output "%saveto%\jlink"
```

This creates the `/yourworkspace/jlink` folder with a custom JRE+JavaFX libraries which you will link to `jpackager`.